# Sync One Drive folder to mobile devices

Tags: onedrive-for-business

We've got several employees that have Android tablets (no access to a Windows PC). The tablets all have One Drive installed. We have a One Drive folder we share with all of the employees. They're all members or owners of the folder.  In order to get the folder to sync to their tablets we have to login to OneDrive.com in a browser for each employee and click the Sync button for the folder.

Is there a policy or setting we can change to force the folder to sync for all members & owners to avoid having to manually click it for each of them?